# how to make the django project in live server

Tags: django

I have a small project with basic crud operations done in django, in my local it works fine, now I have uploaded it into a live domain, and run the project,It has run without any issues,

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 22, 2017 - 10:20:14
Django version 1.11.1, using settings 'callluge.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

So far so good, Now my question is, how could I see this in browser, if i simply access http://127.0.0.1:8001/ browser shows "Unable to connect", 
if my domain name is say "osho.com", how should see the project interface in browser.Please help.

Comment: Have a look at the following link. It has all the details you need to get started doing a production deploy for your django application -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run your server on public ip address of server . 127.0.0.1 is a localhost and it will be available within the your system. outside the machine you can't access this ip address.

So you have to run the server on public ip address of server.

Comment: Yes, and one more thing is, in settings.py there is an option to provide the allowed hosts, ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ ],  here also we have to provide our server ip or domain name.

Comment: Allowed_host is useful for allowing the access from particular host or ip address. If you want to allow it for all ip address then ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'].